# TypeError: Cannot read property 'javascript' of undefined + terser webpack plugin + react js

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4, terser

I recently added terser-webpack-plugin to minify my `create react app` code. But while build the project I got an error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'javascript' of undefined`. Below are some logs from my console. Please let me know of any workarounds or changes to fix it.

Console logs:

```
D:\a>npm run build:qa
> a@1.0.0 build:qa D:\a
> cross-env webpack --env.ENVIRONMENT=qa --config ./webpack.config.js --mode production --progress --colors
D:\a\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:400
      const hooks = compiler.webpack.javascript.JavascriptModulesPlugin.getCompilationHooks(compilation);
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'javascript' of undefined
    at D:\a\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:400:38
```

webpack version im using:

```
"webpack": "^4.44.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
```

Comment: [this is explain,Please review the version carefully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grwio.png)

Answer (score 75):

Hi you are using Webpack 4 and Terser `^5.0.0`. This version of Terser is for Webpack 5, you need to set version `"terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",` in `package.json` file

Comment: your answer solved my problem too! thank you a lot!!!